# SQL Server Computed Column based on transaction tables

Tags: sql-server, database

I am building a web app for tracking Employees Training.

Each Employee will be assigned modules which is made up of different courses.

I have two transaction table which are used to track employees Status for both courses and modules, and another for tracking which courses are assigned to which modules.

Here are the transaction tables.

**Module Content:**

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ModuleContent](
[ModuleID] [int] NOT NULL,
[CourseID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Status] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_ModuleContent] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ModuleID] ASC,
[CourseID] ASC
)
```

**Module Enrollment:**

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ModuleEnrollment](
[EmployeeID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ModuleID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Status] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_ModuleEnrollment_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[EmployeeID] ASC,
[ModuleID] ASC
)
```

**EmployeeCourseStatus:**

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeCourseStatus](
[EmployeeID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ModuleID] [int] NOT NULL,
[CourseID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Status] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_EmployeeCourseStatus] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[EmployeeID] ASC,
[ModuleID] ASC,
[CourseID] ASC
)
```

As of now, the end user would have to update the table `EmployeeCourseStatus` when an employee completes a course to be marked as complete which is fine.

How do I make the `Status` column computed so it's marked as complete based on when an employee completes all the courses assigned to that module in the `ModuleContent` table.

Would I just being using an ALTER table to add the column and join the three tables?

Comment: A computed column can't reference other rows, or objects (unless you're using a scalar functions but that's a different problem). Sounds like you might be better off with a `VIEW`.

Comment: You might want to use a trigger on `EmployeeCourseStatus` to check if all the courses for the module were completed and update the column you want.

Comment: @Larnu okay cool, a view would be a good idea

Answer (score 0):

you should use a function in your computed column and remember to pass primary key to function (`[ModuleID]` and `[CourseID]` and `[ModuleID]`)

and

> Would I just being using an ALTER table to add the column and join the
>   three tables?

you can do this in the function